# Fiddler not seeing API calls from C# HttpClient()

Tags: c#, fiddler, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that is calling a Web API web service.

The calls are working and return 200 OK - both calls to the web service on my local machine AND on a web server.

I have Fiddler running but it is not seeing these calls - only calls to the MVC website (which in turn calls the web service).

How can I see the actual web service calls?

This should be working right? Especially to the web-based web service.

I have stopped referencing `http://localhost` and am using MACHINENAME instead - as recommended in some SO posts. But this doesn't help.

I'm using HttpClient to call it:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://MACHINENAME");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/path", custImp);
}
```

How can I view the web service calls in Fiddler?

Comment: Are the browser, the MVC Website and the WebAPI all located on the same computer?

Comment: yes - and im also testing against a web service that is online.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you start Fiddler, it will change the default system proxy for the current Windows user, so that web requests made by this user are captured by Fiddler.

However, the website runs inside IIS and runs under a different user. You have to make your website use Fiddler by explicitly specifying Fiddler as the web proxy in the web.config file of your MVC application like this (use the port that your Fiddler uses):

```
<configuration>
...
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy  proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />      
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
...
</configuration>
```

References:

- [Debugging Http or Web Services Calls from ASP.NET with Fiddler](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Mar/14/Debugging-Http-or-Web-Services-Calls-from-ASPNET-with-Fiddler)
- [Capturing Traffic from .NET Services with Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler)

---

As [BornToCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057791/borntocode) mentions, it is also possible alternatively to change the application pool identity to your current user.

Comment: OK do you recommend changing the machine config also as recommended here (it's the only way i could get it to work): http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler

Comment: Usually, you only need to change the machine.config for debugging web access from code running in Windows Services. For web applications in IIS, manipulating the file web.config is enough. I have tested and confirmed that the code as shown in my answer works for IIS. Please try again and make sure you use exactly that code as shown.

Comment: I can only get your code working when I modify the machine config. Are you sure fiddler is seeing the API calls that the MVC app is making to the Web API service - rather than just the calls your browser is making to the MVC testing app?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with the web.config you can just change the application pool identity to your current user and it also works. Thank you for a great answer because I never realized that fiddler is set only for current Windows user.

Comment: A very strange side-effect that I noticed from using fiddler without this was that Visual Studio was unable to communicate with its internal services without this in the web.config. I was unable to verify my visual studio license, or install NuGet packages! Adding this fixed it. I still don't quite understand why, but I hope it's of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are running Fiddler as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I add .fiddler so that the requests are captured, example:

```
http://localhost.fiddler:59846
```

Reference:
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/capturing-localhost-traffic